# How to receive an argument in console program?

Tags: c#, console, command-line-arguments

So I want other users to be able to run my programm sending arguments. how to do such thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a Main method (which you'll have with a command-line app) you can access them directly as the args string-array parameter.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
   var arg1 = args[0];
   var arg2 = args[1];
}
```

If you're some other place in your code you can access the static Environment.GetCommandLineArgs method

```
//somewhere in your code
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var arg1 = args[0];
var arg2 = args[1];
```

Answer (score 8):

You mean args when launching? such as `myapp.exe blah blah2 blah3`

Make your main method look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

now `args` is an array of the arguments passed into the program. So in the example case, `args[0] == "blah"`, `args[1] == "blah2"`, etc

Comment: @OP: Just out curiosity... what did you think that `string[] args` in all your programs was used for exactly?

Comment: In C#, the string[] args is optional. Maybe he never saw/used it before now?

Answer (score 4):

The program is run from a method with this signature

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

The parameter `args` will contain the command line arguments, split on space.

Comment: is it split on space, or is it more complicated than that?  if the program where invoked like this: `myapp.exe "blah blah2"`, wouldn't `args[0] == "blah blah2"`?

Comment: @rmeador this is determined by your shell (generally cmd.exe). You are correct that if you want a space in your argument that you need to quote it. Using another shell (such as bash, common in the unix world, or with cygwin on a PC) you can also escape it with a ` \ ` such as `./mypapp.exe blah\ blah2`

Comment: @Dolphin Actually, I think you can escape spaces with backslash on windows (cmd) too. I'm on Unix now, however, so unfortunately I'm not able to test it.

Answer (score 3):

While string[] args works just fine, it's worth mentioning [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

Comment: +1 Here too. I was wondering about that when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can read command line arguments from `Main`'s optional `string[]` parameter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length >= 1)
    {
        string x = args[0];
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Note that the following declaration for the Main method is also valid, but then you don't have access to the command line arguments:

```
static void Main()
{
    // ...
}
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This is supported by default, and the arguments will appear in the args array passed to your program.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

If you say

```
App.exe Hello World What's Up
```

On a command line, you will receive an args array like this:

```
[0] = "Hello"
[1] = "World"
[2] = "What's"
[3] = "Up"
```

It's just up to you to determine what arguments you want, how they will be formatted, etc.

Answer (score 2):

try these:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/csharpoptparse/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx

they basically allow you to define args and parse them in an OO way rather than having to lots of string comparisons and stuff like that.  i used a similar one for java and it was great